# MonoGame game does not work on other pc, when installed by WiX

Tags: xna, monogame, installer

I made a simple tetris game. I wanted to give it to my friend, so that he could test it. I made very fast WiX project and setted up every file from `bin/Debug`. On my PC it works after installing, but when I sent installer file (`.exe` because of `EmbedCab="yes"`) he ran it and it installed, yet game does not work at all. I suppose he does not have some DLLs. Is there a way to install those with WiX and what files should I add there?

I found, that I should use OpenAL installer, but how to run this with WiX?

I found a solution after a lot of searching. I now install OpenAL with `WixUtilExtension` using `CustomAction` tag. Now I found, that i need also ensure that .Net4.5 is installed. I will go googling. Maybe after another hour I will find how to do this :)